What happen if both sides of LED connected to positive?
Question 1:
If we connect both ends of an LED to the positive terminal of a battery, will it create a short circuit and damage the LED?
Question 2:
If connecting both ends of an LED to the positive terminal doesn't damage the LED, can we connect a resistor in series to maintain the potential difference? If so, does it matter whether the resistor is connected before or after the LED?
I am a beginner and having a hard time to understand some of the basics.

In what you described, the battery is not actually part of your "circuit".

can we connect a resistor in series to maintain the potential difference? ... there is no potential difference to maintain

Thanks for responses.

A1) No, nothing happens. The result is exactly the same as connectig the two LED terminals together with a piece of wire or screwdriver. Sure the LED terminals are shorted, but the LED does not care, there is 0V between terminals.
A2) If both terminals of the LED are at same potential, the LED does not light up and no current flows through it. So it does not matter where you put the resistor, before or after the LED. Even if the LED terminals were not shorted together, it still would not matter on which side of the LED the resistor is.

Thank you for your response.

It does nothing, in any case. It's the opposite of a short circuit. You connected both sides to the same potential, so there's no potential difference across the LED and no current flow. Adding a resistor doesn't change anything, because there's no potential difference across that either.

Thank you for your response, sir.

Oh, i thought it would be a short curcuit. I am learning on breadboard right now and if the legs are in the same row, i know it is a short curcuit. But, probably i mixed the two things together in my mind. Because in this question, there is no flow as you said. I need to research about short curcuits a little bit then. Thank you again.
